# Pandas: print with different colors according to label

Tags: python, pandas

I have a binary matrix (0 and 1 - representing a bipartite network) saved into a pd dataframe. Each row and each columns has a label (the modules of the network):

```
df = pdDataFrame(Matrix, columns=cols, index=rows)
```

where cols and rows are the labels.

The pd looks like this:

[image]

I would like to print the matrix in a visual way:

- if the element is 0, then print a white dot
- if the element is 1, print a colored dot, with the color assigned according to the label
  I've been able to print the matrix in a binary way:

```
G = np.zeros((N, M, 3))
G[df>0]=[0, 0, 0]
G[df==0]=[1, 1, 1]
```

How can I change the color (not just black) according to the label?

Comment: Does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **heatmap** is a good way to print *dots* where there is a 1 for visualisation. For labels,  I have synthesized based on your comments.

#### updated

- want grey where labels are not equal
- need a customised **colormap** and also `lambda` function updated to generate values that will use this **colormap**

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
N = 100

M = 200
# sparse binary matrix, p probability it's zero
p = 0.8
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1], (M,N), p=(p, 1-p)),
                  # syntehsize column and row indexes as being labels 0 to 9
                  columns=sorted((list(range(10))*N)[0:N]),
                  index=sorted((list(range(10))*N)[0:M]))


# create the new map, forcing in grey for zero
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap([(.8, .8, .8, 1.0)] + [plt.cm.jet(i) for i in range(plt.cm.jet.N-1)])

# 0 is grey... any other value comes from color map
ax = sns.heatmap(df.apply(lambda s: (s.name==s.index)*s*(s.index+1)), mask=df.eq(0), cmap=cmap )
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please help me apply this function to my case? I'm not really familiar with it.

Comment: I would if I could, but your code has variables **N** and **M** which are undefined.  you talk about labels and functions without stating what they are

Comment: You're right, that's my fault. N is the number of rows of Matrix, while M is the number of columns. While cols and rows are the labels (you can see them in the pictures, they are the numbers that appear above the columns and beside the rows on the left). Should I be more specific?

Comment: I've amended - it you want a more focused answer, focus on a minimum reproducible example similar to my answer for generating a data set

Comment: Is there a way to make a small change? Print with a color if the label of the row is the same as that of the column, otherwise print in grey. For example, if the row label and the column label are both 0, then print in red, if they are both 1 print in blue, while if one is 0 and the other is 1 then print in grey

Comment: done - it does get a bit more involved with how to utilise color map